# Counting fundamental units of real quadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

For a given real quadratic field $K$, the group of units of its ring of integers is $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}\cong(\pm1)\times \mathbb{Z}$ by the Dirichlet unit theorem. For each $\mathcal{O}_K$, pick the fundamental unit as $\epsilon >1$, then $\epsilon=m\sqrt{d}+n$, where $m,n>0$ are integers or half integers. Now for a large variable $x>>1$, define the counting function $$
  u(x):=\sum_{1<\epsilon<x} 1,
$$
where the sum is over all real quadratic fields.

Firstly the sum is finite, since by the above token, there are only finitely many $\epsilon=m\sqrt{d}+n$ with bounded absolute value as $d\rightarrow\infty$.

What asymptotic information is known about $u(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's count

$$ v(x) = \sum_{1 < \mu < x} 1 $$

where $\mu$ ranges over every unit greater than $1$ of every real quadratic field.

Setting $\mu = m \sqrt{d} + n$, we require $n^2 - m^2 d = \pm 1$. Given that equation, the inequalities are equivalent:

$$ 1 < \mu < x \Longleftrightarrow 1 < n < \frac{x^2 \pm 1}{2x} $$

For each choice of half-integer $n$ and choice of sign, there is a unique solution for $m,d$ with $d$ a squarefree integer. This solution will have $m > 0$.

Consequently, we can count units simply by counting the number of half-integers $n$ and counting signs:

$$ v(x) = 2x + O(1)$$

---

Another way to count every unit greater than $1$ is by observing it is a positive power of the fundamental unit. If we count them, their squares, their cubes, and so forth, we get:

$$ v(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{1 < \epsilon^k < x} 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u(x^{1/k}) $$

which we can reverse via inclusion-exclusion to get

$$ u(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(k) v(x^{1/k}) $$

and consequently,

$$ u(x) = 2x - 2\sqrt{x} - 2\sqrt[3]{x} + O(\sqrt[5]{x}) $$

Comment: Thank you Hurkyl for this nice answer! But I do not think there should be the factor $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Dianbin: Basically, you just count all units of all real quadratic fields; every unit of magnitude greater than $1$ can be uniquely written as $\epsilon_d^b$ where $b > 0$ and $\epsilon_d$ is the fundamental unit of discriminant $d$. After thinking about it some more, I was right the first time and I shouldn't have included the $1/2$ factor.

Comment: @Dianbin: Better estimate up. I'm a little embarrassed of the previous one, since it's not often I actually make things a lot harder on myself when trying to make a crude estimate of things!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I want. @Hurkyl

Answer (score 8):

In Proposition 4.1 of [Sarnak](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X82900282) you'll find an asymptotic for the related quantity (take there $p=1$) when one considers all ring discriminants (not just the fundamental field discriminants that you want).  If restricted to field discriminants, the work of [Raulf](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/form.2009.21.issue-2/forum.2009.012/forum.2009.012.xml) obtains such asymptotic formulae (see Lemma 5.1 in that paper).  In both papers, the interest is in obtaining averages for the class number $h(d)$ when the discriminants are arranged according to the size of $\epsilon_d$.